# Removing the repeating elements from a row in a squlite table

Tags: c, sqlite

Please let me know if there is any query where in I remove the repeating entries in a row.

For eg: I have a table which has name with 9 telephone numbers:

```
Name     Tel0  Tel1  Tel2  Tel3  Tel4  Tel5  Tel6  Tel7  Tel8

John       1      2     2     2    3     3     4     5      1
```

The final result should be as shown below:

```
Name     Tel0  Tel1  Tel2  Tel3  Tel4  Tel5  Tel6  Tel7  Tel8

John      1      2    3     4     5
```

regards
   Maddy

Comment: Data stored like this can be difficult to manage, I would suggest normalising the table so that you had one table with ID and Name called, say, Person and another with two fields PersonID and Tel called, perhaps Telephone. This will then allow you to force uniqueness.

Comment: @Tribeca: The table I use in my project looks like this as shown below. Normnalising the  table would make it more complex for me to decode the answer and apply the same logic here. Please let me know what is not clear?

Answer (score 1):

I fear that it will be more complicated to keep this format than to split the table in two as I suggested. If you insist on keeping the current schema then I would suggest that you query the row, organise the fields in application code and then perform an update on the database.

You could also try to use SQL UNION operator to give you a list of the numbers, a UNION by default will remove all duplicate rows:

```
SELECT Name, Tel FROM 
  (SELECT Name, Tel0 AS Tel FROM Person UNION 
   SELECT Name, Tel1 FROM Person UNION
   SELECT Name, Tel2 FROM Person) ORDER BY Name ;
```

Which should give you a result set like this:

```
John|1
John|2
```

You will then have to step through the result set and saving each number into a separate variable (skipping those variables that do not exist) until the "Name" field changes.

```
Tel1 := Null; Tel2 := Null;
Name := ResultSet['Name'];
Tel0 := ResultSet['Tel'];
ResultSet.Next();
if (Name == ResultSet['Name']) {
  Tel1 := ResultSet['Tel'];
} else {
  UPDATE here.
  StartAgain;
}
ResultSet.Next();
if (Name == ResultSet['Name']) {
  Tel2 := ResultSet['Tel'];
} else {
  UPDATE here.
  StartAgain;
}
```

I am not recommending you do this, it is very bad use of a relational database but once implemented in a real language and debugged that should work.